# Cannot start Apache on XAMPP

Tags: java, php, apache, perl, xampp

i can't seem to figure out what is blocking my port. however i rechecked what was blocking it, and XAMPP says apache is. then says to start from the root directory? not really to sure how its running into itself, if it doing what it's saying. also, i cannot edit the configure logs with apache on motepad++, just comes up with a blank new note. thanks!

here is the log---

```html
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Problem detected: Apache Not Found!
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Disabling Apache buttons
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Problem detected!
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" with PID 15972!
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Problem detected!
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" with PID 15972!
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
10:57:21 PM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Comment: looks like its already running

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that skype is not running in your PC while starting Apache. Its because Apache can start only when the port 80 is open. But skype reserves the port. You can exit skype, start Apache, and then start Skype again.

Comment: but port 80 is being used by  "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"

Comment: opps! did you try reinstalling the program?

Comment: Port is unblocked. Now it only tells me to run apache from my root directory. However, start and admin buttons are gray, along with the check boxes still...

Answer (score 0):

You Don't Need to reinstall it just change the port number of your tomcat server by following procedure:

1.C:\xampp\tomcat\conf\server.xml

2. change port number

   ```
         <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
          connectionTimeout="20000"
          redirectPort="8443" />
   ```

8080 to any other that is not used by any other app in your system
ex.1234

it definately works restart your server and then start tomcat......

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this happened to me at work the other day while setting up XAMPP on a Windows 7 laptop.  As soon as the installation completed, I could not start Apache on port 80, because the Apache service was already started, though the XAMPP console showed stopped.  But, Task Manager showed that the httpd service initiated from the XAMPP bin directory.

I tried uninstalling, reinstalling... but what worked was rebooting the laptop right after installing it.  Once Windows came back up, I verified Apache had not started.  I was then able to successfully open the XAMPP console and start Apache.

Silly Windows....

Hope this helps....